# Doubt in Dyson's argument about the divergent nature of the perturbative expansion in QED

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum, perturbation-theory, stability, analyticity

I am trying to understand Dyson's argument about the divergent nature of the perturbative expansion in QED. Quoting his [own words](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0508017)

> [...] let 
>   $$F(e^2)=a_0+a_1e^2+a_2e^4+\ldots$$
>   be a physical quantity which is calculated as a formal power series in $e^2$ by integrating the equations of motion of the theory over a finite or infinite time. Suppose, if possible, that the series...  converges for some positive value of $e^2$; this implies that $F(e^2)$ is an analytic function of $e$ at $e=0$. Then for sufficiently small value of $e$, $F(−e^2)$ will also be a well-behaved analytic function with a convergent power series expansion.

My question is, why does the convergence of the series for some positive value of $e^2$ imply that it must be analytic at $e=0$?

Answer (score 6):

It's a theorem in analysis that if  the  power series converges for some value of $e^2$, it converges uniformly for all values of $e^2$ of lesser absolute magnitude and the resulting function is smooth and infinitely differentiable in this disc.  Thus convergence says that  ground state energy $E_0(e^2)$
cannot be badly behaved for negative $e^2$.  However,   once like unlike charges repel  the vacuum is unstable to   decay into electron positron  pairs. Thus $E_0$ is singular at $e^2=0$, and the series cannot converge.